# Rails Active Model Serializers - how to manually expire cache?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, active-model-serializers

I'm using Active Model Serializers to cache a model in my Rails app. I want it to cache, but I don't want the cache to expire when the associated object (instance of User) updates. What I'd like is to be able to expire it when I want (unrelated to user updating), and for it only to expire when it is forced to do so.

serializer code looks like:

```
class MatchesHashSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  cached
  delegate :cache_key, to: :object

  attribute :matches_hash

  def matches_hash
    ...
  end
end
```

I'd still want the cache associated with the user object, but I just don't want it to expire when the user is updated - i'd only like it to expire by triggering/forcing it to expire with some other mechanism. How would I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: since AMS can be passed the same options as in  ActiveSupport::Cache::Store, we can use the 'delete' method to manually expire the cache. https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers#caching and http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Cache/Store.html#method-i-delete